# install TARGETS given unknown argument "DIRECTORY"

Tags: c++, cmake

Tried to build a project and install directory using cmake. Used following cmakefile.

CMake version used: 3.8.2

```sh
# Specifying minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.2)

# Project name
project(pro LANGUAGES C CXX VERSION 0.1.0)

# Set C++11 compiler
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Global Install Directories
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# Source files
SET(SRC_FILES
    src/file.cpp
)

# Project requirements
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Creating static library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

# Linking opencv dynamically
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

# Set correct Install directories
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Config
    ARCHIVE  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

It is giving me following error while installing the directory

```sh
  install TARGETS given unknown argument "DIRECTORY".

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am not able to understand the error, can anyone pleae help me out? Thank you !

Comment: You use [install(TARGETS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets) flow of the `install` command, and as you can see from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets), signature of that command flow doesn't allow `DIRECTORY` parameter. This is what the error message tells you. If you want to install directory, then you need to use [install(DIRECTORY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-directories) flow of the command.

Comment: yes thanks, sorry for stupid question.